# FunctionRange giving "false"

Tags: functions

I was trying to find the range of a function I obtained  in some context. The code is as follows

`FunctionRange[{1/2 (1 - Sqrt[-1 + 4 Abs[x]] Sqrt[-1 + 4 Abs[z]]),  0 < Abs[x] < 1/4 && 0 < Abs[z] < 1/4}, {Abs[x], Abs[z]}, y]`

The above code when executed gives False. What is the meaning of false and how to find the range of function in this case?

Answer (score 3):

> What is the meaning of false and how to find the range of function in
> this case?

The default for domain is `Reals`

[image]

When it returns `False` it means there is no range in the reals.

```
FunctionRange[{1/2 (1 - Sqrt[-1 + 4 Abs[x]] Sqrt[-1 + 4 Abs[z]]), 
  0 < Abs[x] < 1/4 && 0 < Abs[z] < 1/4}, {Abs[x], 
  Abs[z]}, y]

(*False*)
```

Change to complex

```
FunctionRange[{1/2 (1 - Sqrt[-1 + 4 Abs[x]] Sqrt[-1 + 4 Abs[z]]), 
  0 < Abs[x] < 1/4 && 0 < Abs[z] < 1/4}, {Abs[x], 
  Abs[z]}, y, Complexes]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks. And there are situations when it returns "True" then does it means that all the reals are in the range?

Comment: @tanaypathak that is correct. For example `FunctionRange[y, x, y]` returns trues, means from `-Infinity` to `+Infinity`